# Scrolling background image with boundaries

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have a large background image.  I would like to make it so that when I scroll down the page, the image scrolls down as well... but when it gets to the bottom of the image it does not continue scrolling into white space. How do I go about doing this?

Additionally I would like it to scroll smoothly.

Comment: Either use a large enough image (by scaling it) or repeat the background.

Comment: either post code so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that?

http://jsfiddle.net/hXn9L/

You should play with background-attachment and background-size:

```
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
```

Comment: No I'm talking about something more dynamic, more of an effect.  I have no code because I haven't begun it.